# Which works of the Church Fathers name Jacob the Just as the leader of the Ebionites?

Tags: early-church, church-fathers

I’m having trouble finding the sources that would backup unsourced claims on the Wikipedia article about the Ebionites that they revered Jacob the Just and considered him the successor of the movement while rejecting Paul as an apostate. Does anyone know the exact sources? It would be useful for other questions if we could use the right sources.

Comment: starting point https://www.google.com/search?q=ebionites+james++&hl=en&gl=in&tbm=bks&uact=5

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Is there any basis in the claim that James, the half brother of Jesus, was actually named Jacob and that in Hebrew, it’s Yaakov, after the patriarch who was later renamed Israel (Genesis 32:28; 35:9–10)? Another claim I found is that the half-brother of Jesus was a Jewish sage who served the Messiah from Jerusalem and he had the reputation of being just—hence, the moniker James the Just.

Comment: Is [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebionites) the one you refer to where you say you are having trouble finding the sources to some of the claims made?  If so, then copious references are provided to the source documents in  the article.

Comment: Lesley, the actual name of James is Jacob, check the Greek source. The name was changed by English translators to James to avoid confusing with Genesis Jacob. He is asking for actual sources of those early christian quotes which makes those claims. The scholars seem to only state that it was an offshoot of the original Church of Jerusalem.

Comment: @Michael16 my understanding is that the name change has nothing to do with disambiguating. The historical reason is that King James wanted his name in the Bible and the translator appeased the king. In no other language translation I know of is any kind of distinction made. This is a peculiarity of English language translations only.

Comment: Here is the link to [the article](https://www.foi.org/2023/06/23/who-is-jacob-the-lords-brother/) that makes the connection between James, the half-brother of Jesus, and Jacob the Just.  Re James the Just [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebionites#On_James_the_Just) and re Paul [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebionites#On_Paul_the_Apostle)  are the links to the sources to back up the Wikipedia claims in that article.  I don't understand why you say the claims are unsourced.

Comment: As pointed out by @Lesley the question is factually incorrect and should be closed on that basis, or be drastically edited to conform to the known facts. It could be that the question is just poorly researched and the facts were not properly assimilated.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in your other question, perhaps closed now, is Ebionites did not believe the same things as Christians.

> Of the Lord Jesus Christ (κυριου Ιησου Χριστου). Here on a par with God (θεου) and calls himself not αδελφος (brother) of Jesus, but δουλος. The three terms here as in 2:1 have their full significance: Jesus is the Messiah and Lord. James is not an Ebionite. He accepts the deity of Jesus his brother, difficult as it was for him to do so. The word κυριος is frequent in the LXX for Elohim and Jahweh as the Romans applied it to the emperor in their emperor worship. See 1Co 12:3 for Κυριος Ιησους and Php 2:11 for Κυριος Ιησους Χριστος. [A.T. Robertson Word Pictures James 1](https://ccel.org/ccel/robertson_at/word/word.xxiii.i.html)

> In the Acts and in the Epistle to the Galatians, James appears as the most conservative of the Jewish converts, at the head of the extreme right wing; yet recognizing Paul as the apostle of the Gentiles, giving him the right hand of fellowship, as Paul himself reports, and unwilling to impose upon the Gentile Christians the yoke of circumcision. He must therefore not be identified with the heretical Judaizers (the forerunners of the Ebionites), who hated and opposed Paul, and made circumcision a condition of justification and church membership. He presided at the Council of Jerusalem and proposed the compromise which saved a split in the church. He probably prepared the synodical letter which agrees with his style and has the same greeting formula peculiar to him. [Philip Schaff, History of the Christian Church James the Brother of the Lord](https://ccel.org/ccel/schaff/hcc1/hcc1.i.IV_1.27.html)

Based on these historians, the idea that James the Just led the Ebionites apart from the apostles like Peter and John is false.

At the same time, there is clearly a group that attempted to mix Law and Grace as to one's salvation.

> It was the Ebionites, the Nazarenes, the Elkasaites, the Essenes, which were all Gnostic heresies in a way, but of a moderate and Judeo-Christian Gnosticism in their affinities, it was those heresies, I say, that swarmed at Rome, [Ernest Renan Origens of Christianity Book VI](https://ccel.org/ccel/renan/hadrian_pius/hadrian_pius.xix.html)

**EDIT TO ADD**: The following is from my answer to a similar question.  It is crystal clear that the Ebionites did not believe the same doctrine as Christians.  For example, Christians believe Christ Jesus was born of a virgin, while Ebionites believe Joseph was the father.

Those who are called Ebionites agree that the world was made by God; but their opinions with respect to the Lord are similar to those of Cerinthus and Carpocrates. They use the Gospel according to Matthew only, and repudiate the Apostle Paul, maintaining that he was an apostate from the law. As to the prophetical writings, they endeavour to expound them in a somewhat singular manner: they practise circumcision, persevere in the observance of those customs which are enjoined by the law, and are so Judaic in their style of life, that they even adore Jerusalem as if it were the house of God. Irenaeus AH Book I Chapter XXVI

God, then, was made man, and the Lord did Himself save us, giving us the token of the Virgin. But not as some allege, among those now presuming to expound the Scripture, [thus:] “Behold, a young woman shall conceive, and bring forth a son,”3708 as Theodotion the Ephesian has interpreted, and Aquila of Pontus,3709 both Jewish proselytes. The Ebionites, following these, assert that He was begotten by Joseph; thus destroying, as far as in them lies, such a marvellous dispensation of God, and setting aside the testimony of the prophets which proceeded from God. Irenaeus AH Book III Chapter XXI

Vain also are the Ebionites, who do not receive by faith into their soul the union of God and man, but who remain in the old leaven of [the natural] birth, and who do not choose to understand that the Holy Ghost came upon Mary, and the power of the Most High did overshadow her:4453 wherefore also what was generated is a holy thing, and the Son of the Most High God the Father of all, who effected the incarnation of this being, and showed forth a new [kind of] generation; that as by the former generation we inherited death, so by this new generation we might inherit life. Irenaeus Book V Chapter I

Comment: How could the Ebionites not believe what Christians believe? Given that they were Christians by definition their beliefs were Christian beliefs. Perhaps you meant to say they didn’t have Paulian beliefs?

Comment: See the EDIT TO ADD to again show a contrast between what Christians and Ebionites believed.

Comment: Iraneus was a pagan and it unsurprising that his version of Christianity has a pagan slant unacceptable to Jewish Christians such as the Ebionites. You are going to define what is ‘Christian belief’ on his testimony and exclude what Jewish Christians from an unbroken line to the founder of the movement had to say about what Christians believe?